# Parsing string into list of outputs

Tags: python, string, text, bioinformatics, python-re

I'm working with a text file, which consists of many similar reports of the following structure:

```
['NetNGlyc-1.0 Server Output - DTU Health Tech\n',
 '     Asn-Xaa-Ser/Thr sequons in the sequence output below are highlighted in blue.\n',
 '          Asparagines predicted to be N-glycosylated are highlighted in red.\n',
 "Output for 'Sequence'\n",
 'Name:  Sequence  Length:  923\n',
 'MERGLPLLCAVLALVLAPAGAFRNDKCGDTIKIESPGYLTSPGYPHSYHPSEKCEWLIQAPDPYQRIMINFNPHFDLEDR      80 \n',
 'DCKYDYVEVFDGENENGHFRGKFCGKIAPPPVVSSGPFLFIKFVSDYETHGAGFSIRYEIFKRGPECSQNYTTPSGVIKS     160 \n',
 'PGFPEKYPNSLECTYIVFVPKMSEIILEFESFDLEPDSNPPGGMFCRYDRLEIWDGFPDVGPHIGRYCGQKTPGRIRSSS     240 \n',
 'GILSMVFYTDSAIAKEGFSANYSVLQSSVSEDFKCMEALGMESGEIHSDQITASSQYSTNWSAERSRLNYPENGWTPGED     320 \n',
 'SYREWIQVDLGLLRFVTAVGTQGAISKETKKKYYVKTYKIDVSSNGEDWITIKEGNKPVLFQGNTNPTDVVVAVFPKPLI     400 \n',
 'TRFVRIKPATWETGISMRFEVYGCKITDYPCSGMLGMVSGLISDSQITSSNQGDRNWMPENIRLVTSRSGWALPPAPHSY     480 \n',
 'INEWLQIDLGEEKIVRGIIIQGGKHRENKVFMRKFKIGYSNNGSDWKMIMDDSKRKAKSFEGNNNYDTPELRTFPALSTR     560 \n',
 'FIRIYPERATHGGLGLRMELLGCEVEAPTAGPTTPNGNLVDECDDDQANCHSGTGDDFQLTGGTTVLATEKPTVIDSTIQ     640 \n',
 'SEFPTYGFNCEFGWGSHKTFCHWEHDNHVQLKWSVLTSKTGPIQDHTGDGNFIYSQADENQKGKVARLVSPVVYSQNSAH     720 \n',
 'CMTFWYHMSGSHVGTLRVKLRYQKPEEYDQLVWMAIGHQGDHWKEGRVLLHKSLKLYQVIFEGEIGKGNLGGIAVDDISI     800 \n',
 'NNHISQEDCAKPADLDKKNPEIKIDETGSTPGYEGEGEGDKNISRKPGNVLKTLDPILITIIAMSALGVLLGAVCGVVLY     880 \n',
 'CACWHNGMSERNLSALENYNFELVDGVKLKKDKLNTQSTYSEA\n',
 '................................................................................      80\n',
 '.....................................................................N..........     160\n',
 '................................................................................     240\n',
 '....................N...........................................................     320\n',
 '.................................................................N..............     400\n',
 '................................................................................     480\n',
 '................................................................................     560\n',
 '................................................................................     640\n',
 '................................................................................     720\n',
 '................................................................................     800\n',
 '................................................................................     880\n',
 '...........................................                                          960\n',
 '\n',
 '(Threshold=0.5)\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'SeqName      Position  Potential   Jury    N-Glyc\n',
 '     agreement result\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. \n',
 'Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    \n',
 'Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     \n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Graphics in PostScript\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Go back.\n']
```

The resulting file that I'm trying to get is a list of elements, where each element would be a string, containing only the info that I want to be left. The final list structure that I'm trying to get is something like that:

```
['Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',

'Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n
 Sequence     466 NYSV   0.6178     (7/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',

'Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n
 Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',
...]
```

I managed to separate the outputs with the following code:

```
import re

with open('/path_to_text_file/file.txt', 'r') as file:
    test_output = file.readlines()

test_string = ''.join(map(str, test_output))  # convert the list into string

# here I decided to split the outputs by 'Go back' substring
# 1. first split by "\n\n" preceeding the 'Go back' substring
# 2. then by ".\n" following the 'Go back'
# 3. then by "\n" left 

test_string_split = ' '.join(map(str, ' '.join(map(str, test_string.split('\n\n'))).split('.\n')))


# split into element by *'Go back'* substring
processed_test = ''.join(test_string_split).split('Go back')
```

Now what I have in my hands is a list of elements, where each element comprises a single output. But I haven't managed yet to strip this outputs of all unnecessary text preserving the structure of the list, where each element came from a single report.
I tried the following logic:

```
res = [] # create a list for the final result

# split each output in the text file by '\n'
for output in processed_test: 
    output_split = ''.join(output).split('\n')

    # then check each line of the output for the 'Sequence' substring
    for string in output_split:
        string_el = ''.join(string)
        if re.match("Sequence.*", string_el): 
            res.append(string_el) # save matches to the resulting list
```

But what I get is a list of elements, where each element comprises a separate "Sequence"-line:

```
['Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    ',
 'Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     ',
 'Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     ',
 'Sequence      63 NYTV   0.7796     (9/9)   +++   ',
 'Sequence     209 NITL   0.7032     (8/9)   +     ',
 'Sequence     297 NVSI   0.6256     (8/9)   +     ',
 'Sequence     365 NLSQ   0.6403     (7/9)   +     ',
 'Sequence     522 NTSH   0.5207     (6/9)   +     ',
 'Sequence     696 NCSI   0.6619     (9/9)   ++    ',
...
...
...]
```

Is there a way of parsing a list inside the elements themselves so as to preserve the structure of the list? The idea is that I need to understand from which report comes the info on the sequences.

Comment: Any reason you used `test_output = file.readlines(); test_string = ''.join(map(str, test_output))` rather than simply: `test_output = file.read()`?

Comment: Is the file a list containing strings?  Are you just trying to get the lines in the list that start with **Sequence**?

Comment: @DarrylG no reason for not using ``` file.read() ``` . I’m not very good at Python. 
And Yes, I read the file into a list of strings. Each string is a full-length report. And I want each string in this list to contain only lines starting with **Sequence**

Comment: Is the example you gave for one-group, but you could have several with each separated by "Go back"?  Is there information that should go with each group to identify it?

Comment: @DarrylG The list consists of many similar reports just like the one in the example. Each report ends with “Go back”, which is why I used it to separate the text file into a list of reports. There are no particular groups, all reports are similar but belong to different inputs that were given to a web server. The inputs represented protein sequences. And so I had hoped to clean all the reports in the list so as to leave only the needed info, while being able to address each report in separately in the list by its index. I would need this list to make a Pandas series out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you wanat to do the following:

- Read in the sequence lines as different reports
- Place the multiple reports into a Dataframe
- Output the dataframe as a CSV file

That can be done as follows:

**Code**

```
import ast
import os

def make_reports(file_path):
   
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        stack = [[]]                     # start with 1st report empty

        # Convert string into Python list
        lines = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

        for line in lines:
            # Loop through all lines in list
            if line.startswith('Sequence'):
                # Append Sequence to current group
                stack[-1].append(line)
            elif line.startswith('Go back'):
                stack.append([])    # Start new report

    # Convert to a dataframe, with each Report enumeratd (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...)
    dfs = []
    for i, seqs in enumerate(stack):
        if seqs:
            # TWo column dataframe: Sequence and Report number
            dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({f'Sequences':seqs, 'Report':[i]*len(seqs)}))

    result = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    # Write to results file (uses input file path and append -result to name)
    result.to_csv(f'{os.path.splitext(file_path)[0]}-result.txt', 
                  encoding='utf-8', 
                  index=False)
    return result
```

**Usage**

make_reports('test.txt')

**Input File**: test.txt

Obtained by replicating posted data two more times to obtain multiple reports

```
['NetNGlyc-1.0 Server Output - DTU Health Tech\n',
 '     Asn-Xaa-Ser/Thr sequons in the sequence output below are highlighted in blue.\n',
 '          Asparagines predicted to be N-glycosylated are highlighted in red.\n',
 "Output for 'Sequence'\n",
 'Name:  Sequence  Length:  923\n',
 'MERGLPLLCAVLALVLAPAGAFRNDKCGDTIKIESPGYLTSPGYPHSYHPSEKCEWLIQAPDPYQRIMINFNPHFDLEDR      80 \n',
 'DCKYDYVEVFDGENENGHFRGKFCGKIAPPPVVSSGPFLFIKFVSDYETHGAGFSIRYEIFKRGPECSQNYTTPSGVIKS     160 \n',
 'PGFPEKYPNSLECTYIVFVPKMSEIILEFESFDLEPDSNPPGGMFCRYDRLEIWDGFPDVGPHIGRYCGQKTPGRIRSSS     240 \n',
 'GILSMVFYTDSAIAKEGFSANYSVLQSSVSEDFKCMEALGMESGEIHSDQITASSQYSTNWSAERSRLNYPENGWTPGED     320 \n',
 'SYREWIQVDLGLLRFVTAVGTQGAISKETKKKYYVKTYKIDVSSNGEDWITIKEGNKPVLFQGNTNPTDVVVAVFPKPLI     400 \n',
 'TRFVRIKPATWETGISMRFEVYGCKITDYPCSGMLGMVSGLISDSQITSSNQGDRNWMPENIRLVTSRSGWALPPAPHSY     480 \n',
 'INEWLQIDLGEEKIVRGIIIQGGKHRENKVFMRKFKIGYSNNGSDWKMIMDDSKRKAKSFEGNNNYDTPELRTFPALSTR     560 \n',
 'FIRIYPERATHGGLGLRMELLGCEVEAPTAGPTTPNGNLVDECDDDQANCHSGTGDDFQLTGGTTVLATEKPTVIDSTIQ     640 \n',
 'SEFPTYGFNCEFGWGSHKTFCHWEHDNHVQLKWSVLTSKTGPIQDHTGDGNFIYSQADENQKGKVARLVSPVVYSQNSAH     720 \n',
 'CMTFWYHMSGSHVGTLRVKLRYQKPEEYDQLVWMAIGHQGDHWKEGRVLLHKSLKLYQVIFEGEIGKGNLGGIAVDDISI     800 \n',
 'NNHISQEDCAKPADLDKKNPEIKIDETGSTPGYEGEGEGDKNISRKPGNVLKTLDPILITIIAMSALGVLLGAVCGVVLY     880 \n',
 'CACWHNGMSERNLSALENYNFELVDGVKLKKDKLNTQSTYSEA\n',
 '................................................................................      80\n',
 '.....................................................................N..........     160\n',
 '................................................................................     240\n',
 '....................N...........................................................     320\n',
 '.................................................................N..............     400\n',
 '................................................................................     480\n',
 '................................................................................     560\n',
 '................................................................................     640\n',
 '................................................................................     720\n',
 '................................................................................     800\n',
 '................................................................................     880\n',
 '...........................................                                          960\n',
 '\n',
 '(Threshold=0.5)\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'SeqName      Position  Potential   Jury    N-Glyc\n',
 '     agreement result\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. \n',
 'Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    \n',
 'Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     \n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Graphics in PostScript\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Go back.\n',
 'NetNGlyc-1.0 Server Output - DTU Health Tech\n',
 '     Asn-Xaa-Ser/Thr sequons in the sequence output below are highlighted in blue.\n',
 '          Asparagines predicted to be N-glycosylated are highlighted in red.\n',
 "Output for 'Sequence'\n",
 'Name:  Sequence  Length:  923\n',
 'MERGLPLLCAVLALVLAPAGAFRNDKCGDTIKIESPGYLTSPGYPHSYHPSEKCEWLIQAPDPYQRIMINFNPHFDLEDR      80 \n',
 'DCKYDYVEVFDGENENGHFRGKFCGKIAPPPVVSSGPFLFIKFVSDYETHGAGFSIRYEIFKRGPECSQNYTTPSGVIKS     160 \n',
 'PGFPEKYPNSLECTYIVFVPKMSEIILEFESFDLEPDSNPPGGMFCRYDRLEIWDGFPDVGPHIGRYCGQKTPGRIRSSS     240 \n',
 'GILSMVFYTDSAIAKEGFSANYSVLQSSVSEDFKCMEALGMESGEIHSDQITASSQYSTNWSAERSRLNYPENGWTPGED     320 \n',
 'SYREWIQVDLGLLRFVTAVGTQGAISKETKKKYYVKTYKIDVSSNGEDWITIKEGNKPVLFQGNTNPTDVVVAVFPKPLI     400 \n',
 'TRFVRIKPATWETGISMRFEVYGCKITDYPCSGMLGMVSGLISDSQITSSNQGDRNWMPENIRLVTSRSGWALPPAPHSY     480 \n',
 'INEWLQIDLGEEKIVRGIIIQGGKHRENKVFMRKFKIGYSNNGSDWKMIMDDSKRKAKSFEGNNNYDTPELRTFPALSTR     560 \n',
 'FIRIYPERATHGGLGLRMELLGCEVEAPTAGPTTPNGNLVDECDDDQANCHSGTGDDFQLTGGTTVLATEKPTVIDSTIQ     640 \n',
 'SEFPTYGFNCEFGWGSHKTFCHWEHDNHVQLKWSVLTSKTGPIQDHTGDGNFIYSQADENQKGKVARLVSPVVYSQNSAH     720 \n',
 'CMTFWYHMSGSHVGTLRVKLRYQKPEEYDQLVWMAIGHQGDHWKEGRVLLHKSLKLYQVIFEGEIGKGNLGGIAVDDISI     800 \n',
 'NNHISQEDCAKPADLDKKNPEIKIDETGSTPGYEGEGEGDKNISRKPGNVLKTLDPILITIIAMSALGVLLGAVCGVVLY     880 \n',
 'CACWHNGMSERNLSALENYNFELVDGVKLKKDKLNTQSTYSEA\n',
 '................................................................................      80\n',
 '.....................................................................N..........     160\n',
 '................................................................................     240\n',
 '....................N...........................................................     320\n',
 '.................................................................N..............     400\n',
 '................................................................................     480\n',
 '................................................................................     560\n',
 '................................................................................     640\n',
 '................................................................................     720\n',
 '................................................................................     800\n',
 '................................................................................     880\n',
 '...........................................                                          960\n',
 '\n',
 '(Threshold=0.5)\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'SeqName      Position  Potential   Jury    N-Glyc\n',
 '     agreement result\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. \n',
 'Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    \n',
 'Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     \n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Graphics in PostScript\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Go back.\n',
 'NetNGlyc-1.0 Server Output - DTU Health Tech\n',
 '     Asn-Xaa-Ser/Thr sequons in the sequence output below are highlighted in blue.\n',
 '          Asparagines predicted to be N-glycosylated are highlighted in red.\n',
 "Output for 'Sequence'\n",
 'Name:  Sequence  Length:  923\n',
 'MERGLPLLCAVLALVLAPAGAFRNDKCGDTIKIESPGYLTSPGYPHSYHPSEKCEWLIQAPDPYQRIMINFNPHFDLEDR      80 \n',
 'DCKYDYVEVFDGENENGHFRGKFCGKIAPPPVVSSGPFLFIKFVSDYETHGAGFSIRYEIFKRGPECSQNYTTPSGVIKS     160 \n',
 'PGFPEKYPNSLECTYIVFVPKMSEIILEFESFDLEPDSNPPGGMFCRYDRLEIWDGFPDVGPHIGRYCGQKTPGRIRSSS     240 \n',
 'GILSMVFYTDSAIAKEGFSANYSVLQSSVSEDFKCMEALGMESGEIHSDQITASSQYSTNWSAERSRLNYPENGWTPGED     320 \n',
 'SYREWIQVDLGLLRFVTAVGTQGAISKETKKKYYVKTYKIDVSSNGEDWITIKEGNKPVLFQGNTNPTDVVVAVFPKPLI     400 \n',
 'TRFVRIKPATWETGISMRFEVYGCKITDYPCSGMLGMVSGLISDSQITSSNQGDRNWMPENIRLVTSRSGWALPPAPHSY     480 \n',
 'INEWLQIDLGEEKIVRGIIIQGGKHRENKVFMRKFKIGYSNNGSDWKMIMDDSKRKAKSFEGNNNYDTPELRTFPALSTR     560 \n',
 'FIRIYPERATHGGLGLRMELLGCEVEAPTAGPTTPNGNLVDECDDDQANCHSGTGDDFQLTGGTTVLATEKPTVIDSTIQ     640 \n',
 'SEFPTYGFNCEFGWGSHKTFCHWEHDNHVQLKWSVLTSKTGPIQDHTGDGNFIYSQADENQKGKVARLVSPVVYSQNSAH     720 \n',
 'CMTFWYHMSGSHVGTLRVKLRYQKPEEYDQLVWMAIGHQGDHWKEGRVLLHKSLKLYQVIFEGEIGKGNLGGIAVDDISI     800 \n',
 'NNHISQEDCAKPADLDKKNPEIKIDETGSTPGYEGEGEGDKNISRKPGNVLKTLDPILITIIAMSALGVLLGAVCGVVLY     880 \n',
 'CACWHNGMSERNLSALENYNFELVDGVKLKKDKLNTQSTYSEA\n',
 '................................................................................      80\n',
 '.....................................................................N..........     160\n',
 '................................................................................     240\n',
 '....................N...........................................................     320\n',
 '.................................................................N..............     400\n',
 '................................................................................     480\n',
 '................................................................................     560\n',
 '................................................................................     640\n',
 '................................................................................     720\n',
 '................................................................................     800\n',
 '................................................................................     880\n',
 '...........................................                                          960\n',
 '\n',
 '(Threshold=0.5)\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'SeqName      Position  Potential   Jury    N-Glyc\n',
 '     agreement result\n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 'Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     \n',
 'Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. \n',
 'Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    \n',
 'Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     \n',
 'Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     \n',
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Graphics in PostScript\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Go back.\n']
```

**Output** File: test-results.txt

Columns are Sequences, Report (for report index)

```
Sequences,Report
"Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     
",0
"Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     
",0
"Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     
",0
"Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. 
",0
"Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    
",0
"Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     
",0
"Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     
",0
"Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     
",1
"Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     
",1
"Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     
",1
"Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. 
",1
"Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    
",1
"Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     
",1
"Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     
",1
"Sequence     150 NYTT   0.5361     (5/9)   +     
",2
"Sequence     261 NYSV   0.5599     (6/9)   +     
",2
"Sequence     300 NWSA   0.4157     (6/9)   -     
",2
"Sequence     386 NPTD   0.7736     (9/9)   +++  WARNING: PRO-X1. 
",2
"Sequence     522 NGSD   0.3918     (9/9)   --    
",2
"Sequence     842 NISR   0.4662     (6/9)   -     
",2
"Sequence     892 NLSA   0.4099     (6/9)   -     
",2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this where input is your current output. This splits your list into 3 parts.

```py
import numpy as np

input = ""

output = []

splitted = np.array_split(input, 3)

for listt in splitted:
    output.append("\n".join(listt))

print(output)
```